# App "shutdown" event

Tags: android

### Context

A client-server app where the server is a provider of a large graph of interrelated data. Parts of the graph are downloaded on demand by the client, displayed to the user, and stored locally in a database, in order to avoid requesting them again.

Different types of nodes in the graph are requested (and displayed) by different activities. At any time, many activities can be present on the task, each displaying its own nodes.

Occasionally, the graph changes and the server presents a completely new graph to the app.

In order to know that this happened, the client stores (say, in shared prefs), the revision of the graph it is familiar with. When requesting new data, it tells the server this revision. The server compares the revision it was asked for with its current revision, and if they are different, responds with "graph revision mismatch", rather than the data.

When the client receives such a response, it tells the user that the graph was updated, and (re)starts its root activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK, effectively "restarting" the app.

### Issue

We want to minimise the number of times we are forced to restart the app in this manner. For this purpose, the server will send the client a GCM message, informing it that the graph has changed.

The problem is this: when the client receives such a message, how do we know when it's "safe" to update the locally stored revision?

If there are activities running, or "saved" (in the sense of saveInstanceState), then we consider it "unsafe" to update the local revision, as it will cause inconsistency between the state of these activities (either in memory, or saved) and the data they will receive from the server under the new revision.

### Solutions

Our current solution is to update the locally stored version in Application.onCreate(), but this solution doesn't work if we add long-running Services to the app.

Another approach we are considering is to use Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks and trigger an update when the number of non-destroyed activities becomes 0. This approach has two problems, however:

- It doesn't solve the issue of "saved" (in the sense of onSaveInstanceState) activities, as their saved state can contain references to the graph - for example, the identifier of the node they were asked to display in their Intent. When they are restarted, they may crash or display wrong data because of this. We can, however, at least detect this state by storing the revision in onSaveInstanceState, and comparing it to the current revision when such an activity is recreated.
- **The bigger problem**: I'm not sure when, if at all, Android will destroy all activities in the app's task. Perhaps some versions of Android will never do that, if they have enough memory. Either way, I don't think there is a promise that it will ever do that, especially if the app has long-running Services.

Comment: The GCM implementation is a nice addition. But why are you doing a `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` to refresh the UI in the first place?

Comment: "it will cause inconsistency between the state of these activities (either in memory, or saved) and the data they will receive from the server under the new revision" -- then update the activities when you get the fresh data, or at least notify them that the fresh data is available. For example, use an event bus, so your services that is retrieving the data can send out a `UpdatedChartEvent` or something that your UI layer can subscribe to.

Comment: @shkschneider This guarantees us a "fresh" instance of the task.  CommonsWare, We don't update the activities because (a) there are many of them and the logic for updating each one is different, (b) some of them can't necessarily update (for example, because the node they were displaying doesn't exist anymore) and (c) we don't want to update the UI while the user is looking at it, or maybe even interacting with it.